# firefox: how to see text in input fields with black background set in preferences?

Tags: css, firefox

Input fields don't take over the text color from preferences. The text stays black and so cannot be seen on black background.

It is reported that something like

```
@-moz-document url-prefix(http) {
    input {
         color: #FF0000 !important;
    } 
}
```

in ~/.mozilla/firefox/.../chrome/userContent.css should change the text color of input fields, but Firefox 21 has changed userContent.css location. Where is it now on Linux and will this still work?

Recently I found that the Stylish add-on allows to add user styles and adding the above worked. I can use firefox as main browser again. Still the question is, how to do it without Stylish.

Comment: In firefox 30 the Stylish add-on method does not work any more.

Comment: Someone agreed to fix this in Firefox Core if the bug was updated to include all effected element types.  I don't know if it's assigned, but there are people who are willing to work on it if we can figure out all the elements, at least.

Answer (score 2):

Below is what I use in stylish for gmail when using XFCE in Linux. Don't know why, but GTK color schemes seem to screw up web browsing. white text on white backgrounds.. black text on black backgrounds.. ugh... I've tried the user*.css workarounds and no one solution works for everything. Stylish is best as it tailors preferences for any website you want.

```
input[type="email"], 
input[type="number"], 
input[type="tel"], 
input[type="text"], 
input[type="url"]
{
  background: black;
  color: #00FF00 !important;
}

input[type="password"]
{
  background: yellow;
  color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put it in the root of your profile folder. To find your profile folder:

1. Goto about:support
2. Click the button next to the profile folder and it should open in your file utility.
3. Put userContent.css in that folder.

Comment: I tried this on a different machine having FF25 without Stylish. Just putting userContent.css there and restarting did not change the input text color to red. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on
Linux Mint 18.3 Sylvia
Firefox 59.0.2 (64-bit)

In Preferences->Themes->Controls  I had selected Mint-Y-Dark

As far as I have found, selecting any other options there fixes the issue for me.

If you REALLY want a completely dark GTK theme, this is not a solution, of course. But, it does pin down the issue a bit.

A possible work-around is https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/dark-gtk-theme-screws-up-firefox-4-0-a-877249/